# Defining Two Things per Case Statement

Tags: verilog

I am using a `case` statement to determine what seven seg LED digit is to turn on. I am also trying to use the same `case` statement to determine which actual number to show on that digit. My broken code:

```
always @(*)
begin
    case(sel_state)

        2'b00: selector = 3'b000; //1st digit
               BCD = BCD1;
               
        2'b01: selector = 3'b100; //2nd digit
        2'b01: BCD = BCD2;
        2'b10: selector = 3'b110;  //3rd digit
        2'b10: BCD = BCD3;
        2'b11: selector = 3'b001;  //4th digit
        2'b11: BCD = BCD4;
        
        
        default: selector = 3'b000;
    endcase
end
```

As you can see, I was messing around with different syntax, but it doesn't seem to like anything I've tried. If I modeled the first `case` like the other 3, the `case` switches between selectors but doesn't change what BCD equals. If I switch the order, BCD changes but selector doesn't. Does anyone know a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the only thing you *haven't* tried is using a [block statement](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00002.htm), which is exactly the thing you need:

```
case(sel_state)
    2'b00: begin
        selector = 3'b000;
        BCD = BCD1;
    end
    2'b01: begin
        selector = 3'b100;
        BCD = BCD2;
    end
    : :
endcase
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `begin`-`end`

```
always @* begin
  case(sel_state)
    2'b00: begin //1st digit
      selector = 3'b000;
      BCD = BCD1;
    end
    2'b01: begin //2nd digit
      selector = 3'b100; 
      BCD = BCD2;
    end
    // ... others ...
  endcase
end
```